# How to use stackdriver for dataflow workers?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Somewhat a follow up from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129663/how-to-set-disksourceimage-in-google-data-flow-pipeline) to be able to have monitoring for dataflow pool of workers.

The goal is to have workers spawned by dataflow to use an image that already has the stackdriver installed and would report directly to the 
[stackdriver console](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/)

- Create an ubuntu image with drivers installed
- Registered driver with API key for the base image
- Using image for dataflow workers via `options.setDiskSourceImage(...)`

Despite the steps executed above none of the instance show up in my stackdriver console. Any ideas?

Comment: HI I provided an answer to your question. However I'd like to know what information you ultimately want out of stackdriver. That might allow us to suggest a better alternative for obtaining that information or create a feature request to surface that information better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution won't work. If you want to start the stackdriver agent (or any agent for that matter) on the VM there are two ways you could do this.

1. At the project level, use the startup script metadata variable to run a script on all VMs at startup.

   - Configure this script to install and configure the stack driver agent
   - If you don't want to run this script on all VMs you'd need to either

     - Override the startup script metadata variable on VMs you don't want to run the script or,
     - Configure the startup script to do nothing on non-Dataflow VMs.
2. Create a process (separate from your Dataflow job) which ssh's into each Dataflow VM and installs and runs the agent.

**Disclaimer** I would advise against implementing either solution unless you have a strong and immediate need. Both solutions rely on Dataflow's current internal workings and are not part of any external contract. Consequently, both solutions are liable to break without warning if Dataflow's implementation changes.

Using a custom disk image with Dataflow is not a viable option. The flag diskSourceImage is deprecated and will be removed in a future SDK release. The reason it is no longer supported is because the Dataflow service relies on versioned resources in the VM image. So Dataflow needs control of the VM image so that we can upgrade it as necessary. If users supply their own custom images we have no way of keeping them in sync with the requirements of the Dataflow service.

Comment: I've noticed recently that *some* errors from dataflow workers are being reported to stackdriver, though it seems intermittent. Is there some movement here?